# How to turn off logging for Tealium web?

Tags: javascript, tealium

When I use tealium on `dev` env I can see a lot of info in my console that I don't need.

As I understand on each `utag.view()` or `utag.link()` Tealium calls `log()` function.

How can I turn this behavior off?

I only found some info [for mobile developers who met same problem](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tealium-iQ-Tag-Management/How-do-I-turn-off-logging-for-Tealium-SDK-on-iOS/td-p/17196), but have no ideas how to do that for web.

What I can see in Tealium source is following:

```
if (b["tealium_environment"] !== "prod" || b["cp.utagdb"] === "true") {
  console.log(...);
}
```

So, it seems like the only way is to set `tealium_environment` to prod... but I think it's not an option, cause as I assume my prod settings will be used for my local dev.

Answer (score 1):

The debug output that you are sharing from the code is specific to your Tealium profile and is not a default behaviour for Tealium profiles.

You could find that extension and either disable it, or add some additional logging on it (e.g. you could set a condition to not log if a cookie named ignore_teal_logs was set to true).

Comment: It's not clear for me how to configure Tealium profile. Where to look? In the docs I can see "profile" only for mobile developers. I have some "utag_cfg_ovrd" and "utag_data" variables in my code, but don't think this is a "profile" I'm looking for